# printStack error when running blockMesh in OpenFOAM

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, openfoam

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/AugustoRiedinger/gimap_rodFoamBaseCase/blob/master/solverImplementation2020.pdf) on how to implement a solver, but I'm having troubles setting up the case.

The original case can be found [here](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/%7Ehani/kurser/OS_CFD_2020/lectureNotes/rodFoamCase.tgz). At first, when running `blockMesh` my version of OpenFOAM didn't recognize `#eval()` in `blockMeshDict`, so I changed it for `#calc`:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  1.5                                   |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      http://www.openfoam.org               |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

FoamFile
{
    version         2.0;
    format          ascii;
    class           dictionary;
    object          blockMeshDict;
}

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

scale 1e-4;

mergeType points; //Or: blockMesh -merge-points

wedgeAngle              2.5;
rodRadius               9.9;
airRadius               999;
tanAlpha                #calc"tan(0.5*degToRad($wedgeAngle))";
posRodZ                 #calc"$rodRadius*$tanAlpha";
negRodZ                 #calc"-$posRodZ";
posAirZ                 #calc"$airRadius*$tanAlpha";
negAirZ                 #calc"-$posAirZ";

vertices        
(
  (0 0 0)                   // vertex #0
  (100 0 0)                 // vertex #1
  (100 $rodRadius $posRodZ) // vertex #2
  (0 $rodRadius  $posRodZ)  // vertex #3
  (0 $rodRadius $negRodZ)   // vertex #4
  (100 $rodRadius $negRodZ) // vertex #5
  (0 $airRadius $posAirZ)   // vertex #6
  (100 $airRadius $posAirZ) // vertex #7
  (100 $airRadius $negAirZ) // vertex #8
  (0 $airRadius $negAirZ)   // vertex #9    
);

blocks          
(
  hex (0 1 5 4 0 1 2 3) (30 6 1)   simpleGrading (1 1 1)    // block #0
  hex (4 5 8 9 3 2 7 6) (30 599 1) simpleGrading (1 1 1)    // block #1
);

edges           
(
);

boundary
(
    leftWall
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (3 4 0 0)
        );
    }
    rightWall
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (1 5 2 1)
        );
    }
    
    atmosphereTop 
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (9 6 7 8)
        );
    }

    atmosphereRight
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (3 6 9 4)
        );
    }

    atmosphereLeft
    {
        type patch;
        faces
        (
            (5 8 7 2)
        );
    }

    axis   
    {
        type empty;
        faces
        (
            (0 1 1 0)
        );
    }

    rodBack 
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (0 4 5 1)
        );
    }

    rodFront  
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (0 1 2 3)
        );
    }

    airBack 
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (4 9 8 5)
        );
    }

    airFront  
    {
        type wedge;
        faces
        (
            (3 2 7 6)
        );
    }
);

mergePatchPairs
(
);

// ************************************************************************* //
```

And now, when running `blockMesh`, I get the following errors:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
  =========                 |
  \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
   \\    /   O peration     | Website:  https://openfoam.org
    \\  /    A nd           | Version:  9
     \\/     M anipulation  |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 9-c8374a4890ad
Exec   : blockMesh
Date   : Dec 16 2021
Time   : 12:59:36
Host   : "endeavouros"
PID    : 346839
I/O    : uncollated
Case   : /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase
nProcs : 1
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster (fileModificationSkew 10)
allowSystemOperations : Allowing user-supplied system call operations

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Create time

Reading "blockMeshDict"

Creating block mesh from
    "system/blockMeshDict"
Using #calcEntry at line 26 in file "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict"
Using #codeStream with "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6.so"
Creating new library in "dynamicCode/_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6.so"
"/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/codeTemplates/dynamicCode/codeStreamTemplate.C" "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6/codeStreamTemplate.C"
Invoking "wmake -s libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6"
wmake libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6
    ln: ./lnInclude
    wmkdep: codeStreamTemplate.C
    Ctoo: codeStreamTemplate.C
    ld: /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6/../platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6.so
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Opening cached dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_28b21b5898ba159392899d5ac4d05a7158e0c6d6.so"
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Using #calcEntry at line 27 in file "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict"
Using #codeStream with "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be.so"
Creating new library in "dynamicCode/_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be.so"
"/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/codeTemplates/dynamicCode/codeStreamTemplate.C" "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be/codeStreamTemplate.C"
Invoking "wmake -s libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be"
wmake libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be
    ln: ./lnInclude
    wmkdep: codeStreamTemplate.C
    Ctoo: codeStreamTemplate.C
    ld: /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be/../platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be.so
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Opening cached dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_efc80fd5ffbc4db1928cd9ff3362f686671433be.so"
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Using #calcEntry at line 28 in file "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict"
Using #codeStream with "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79.so"
Creating new library in "dynamicCode/_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79.so"
"/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/codeTemplates/dynamicCode/codeStreamTemplate.C" "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79/codeStreamTemplate.C"
Invoking "wmake -s libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79"
wmake libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79
    ln: ./lnInclude
    wmkdep: codeStreamTemplate.C
    Ctoo: codeStreamTemplate.C
    ld: /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79/../platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79.so
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Opening cached dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_dc962d55c61555e401d9aa57fd57792f105fea79.so"
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Using #calcEntry at line 29 in file "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict"
Using #codeStream with "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4.so"
Creating new library in "dynamicCode/_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4.so"
"/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/codeTemplates/dynamicCode/codeStreamTemplate.C" "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4/codeStreamTemplate.C"
Invoking "wmake -s libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4"
wmake libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4
    ln: ./lnInclude
    wmkdep: codeStreamTemplate.C
    Ctoo: codeStreamTemplate.C
    ld: /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4/../platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4.so
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Opening cached dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_4510c2296fa7a962a6a70dda03e9219ebc01dac4.so"
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Using #calcEntry at line 30 in file "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict"
Using #codeStream with "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64.so"
Creating new library in "dynamicCode/_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64.so"
"/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/codeTemplates/dynamicCode/codeStreamTemplate.C" "/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64/codeStreamTemplate.C"
Invoking "wmake -s libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64"
wmake libso /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64
    ln: ./lnInclude
    wmkdep: codeStreamTemplate.C
    Ctoo: codeStreamTemplate.C
    ld: /home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64/../platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64.so
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Opening cached dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/dynamicCode/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libcodeStream_0af64279ad3a68c6091e4927dfe1317848075c64.so"
codeStream : dictionary:"/home/ariedinger/uni/gimap/openfoam/03emf/01huang/0rodFoam/rodFoamCase/system/blockMeshDict" master-only-reading:1
Creating block edges
No non-planar block faces defined
Creating topology blocks
#0  Foam::error::printStack(Foam::Ostream&) at ??:?
#1  Foam::sigFpe::sigHandler(int) at ??:?
#2  ? in "/usr/lib/libc.so.6"
#3  Foam::face::centre(Foam::Field<Foam::Vector<double> > const&) const at ??:?
#4  Foam::blockDescriptor::check(Foam::Istream const&) at ??:?
#5  Foam::blockDescriptor::blockDescriptor(Foam::dictionary const&, int, Foam::Field<Foam::Vector<double> > const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockEdge> const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockFace> const&, Foam::Istream&) at ??:?
#6  Foam::block::block(Foam::dictionary const&, int, Foam::Field<Foam::Vector<double> > const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockEdge> const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockFace> const&, Foam::Istream&) at ??:?
#7  Foam::block::New(Foam::dictionary const&, int, Foam::Field<Foam::Vector<double> > const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockEdge> const&, Foam::PtrList<Foam::blockFace> const&, Foam::Istream&) at ??:?
#8  void Foam::PtrList<Foam::block>::read<Foam::block::iNew>(Foam::Istream&, Foam::block::iNew const&) at ??:?
#9  Foam::blockMesh::createTopology(Foam::IOdictionary const&, Foam::word const&) at ??:?
#10  Foam::blockMesh::blockMesh(Foam::IOdictionary const&, Foam::word const&) at ??:?
#11  ? in "/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/blockMesh"
#12  __libc_start_main in "/usr/lib/libc.so.6"
#13  ? in "/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/blockMesh"
fish: Job 2, 'blockMesh' terminated by signal SIGFPE (Floating point exception)
```

So, I'm a bit at lost on where to look and I'd appreciate some tips to try and solve the error.

Besides changing `#eval()` for `#calc` in `blockMeshDict`, everything else is pretty much the same as in the original case but [here are the rest of my files](https://github.com/AugustoRiedinger/gimap_rodFoamBaseCase/tree/master/rodFoamCase).

The given case appears to be built for OpenFOAM v2, and I'm trying to run it on OpenFOAM v9 (installed from the package `openfoam-org` from the AUR). So, maybe that would be a problem? Nonetheless, in the [course](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/%7Ehani/kurser/OS_CFD/) the case was given in 2020 (look at `Implement electromagnetic solver Case: rodFoamCase.tgz` in Proceedings 2020).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worthwhile to test with "openfoam-com" as well to see if there is a difference there. Can either use an AUR recipe or (probably faster) test with a docker instance and openfom.com

https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/docker